# Add Carthage support to third-party libraries

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, sdk, carthage

So I have this GoogleSignIn SDK, which I want to include in my project. It doesn't support Carthage. Is there a way for me to add this SDK to my project using Carthage? (Maybe creating a framework, that includes those frameworks, is a solution?)